# Graph-structured databases and Php

Tags: php, database, database-design, nosql, graph-databases

I want to use a graph database using php. Can you point out some resources on where to get started? Is there any example code / tutorial out there? Or are there any other methods of storing data that relate to each other in totally random/abstract situations?

-

Very abstract example of the relations needed: John relates to Mary, both relate to School, John is Tall, Mary is Short, John has Blue Eyes, Mary has Green Eyes, query I want is which people are related to 'Short people that have Green Eyes and go to School' -> answer John

-

Another example:

```
    TrackA -> ArtistA
           -> ArtistB

           -> AlbumA -----> [ label ]
           -> AlbumB -----> [   A   ]

           -> TrackA:Remix
           -> Genre:House

           -> [ Album ] -----> [ label ]
   TrackB  -> [   C   ]        [   B   ]
```

Example queries:

Which Genre is TrackB closer to? answer: House - because it's related to Album C, which is related to TrackA and is related to Genre:House

Get all Genre:House related albums of Label A : result: AlbumA, AlbumB - because they both have TrackA which is related to Genre:House

-

It is possible in MySQL but it would require a fixed set of attributes/columns for each item and a complex non-flexible query, instead I need every attribute to be an item by itself and instead of 'belonging' to something, to be 'related' to something.

Comment: What is the difference between "belonging to something and "being related to something" (besides using a different word)?

Comment: @Joel L: By belonging I mean like attributes that an item has, and related is how items are related to each other other than one being the attribute of the other. Like Tracks belong to Artist but the same Track can have more than one Artist. Using the parent/child method you would need to duplicate the same child (track) to every parent (artist) plus a Track can be in more than one Album and in more than one Label. How would you describe a relationship like this without using graphs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's some work going on to make the [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) graph database available from PHP, see [this wiki page](http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/PHP) for more information! Regarding how to model your domain as a graph, the [user mailing list](http://neo4j.org/community/list/) tends to be pretty awesome.

Update: there's now a short [getting started blog post](http://onewheeledbicycle.com/2010/06/01/getting-started-with-neo4j-rest-api-and-php/) for a PHP neo4j REST client.

Comment: neo4j REST client query quite slow if compare to mysql

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me a little bit like a "typical" [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) problem... which is a quite different programming language than PHP. But perhaps you could work with popen.

Or you define an SQL table with columns [ id, predicate, atom1, atom2 ], to store the truthness of "Mary has Green Eyes": predicate = "has", atom1 = "Mary", atom2 = "Green Eyes".

Now you could join and filter the predicates and attributes with the SQL of your choice.

Comment: I think you would need a row for every kind of relationship which can be quite a few rows if you handle a lot of data such as a music or movie database with tags and authors, artists, genre and more relationships?

Comment: Yes, but almost every graph tends to have an exponential number of edges ("relationships") between nodes ("atoms"), which makes solving graph problem (especially if horizontal partitioning is also used) using traditional databases that much harder.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a semantic web problem. So you have to figure out how you can use PHP and the semantic web together. Maybe this link http://bnode.org/blog/2009/05/25/back-from-new-york-semantic-web-for-php-developers-trip can help?

Answer (score 1):

It kind of sounds like you should approach it this way:

1) Code a graph object that will let you query your data the way you want.

2) Write a persistence layer for your object

3) optimize the calls that do your query's in the graph object to use database calls when appropriate (for example, if you need to conserve memory).

Comment: Yes that can be a solution, I was thinking if there were any classes already out there for that but it seems that graph structures have very little attention at the moment and the code you can find is very few. I guess I'm going to have to invent the wheel...

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to pick a Java-based graph DB like OrientDB or neo4j and then use it via the [PHP/Java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/). In the near future neo4j (and at some point OrientDB as well) should get native php support and you can replace the bridge with native access.

Answer (score 1):

well taking into account this question is one year old, it might still be interesting to note that you can do such a query with every rdf datastore that supports sparql or comparable languages.

Answer (score 0):

Take also a look to this article about the usage of OrientDB with PHP: http://www.odino.org/346/orientdb-the-graph-db-for-the-web

Answer (score 0):

You can also find a Rexster client for php : https://github.com/PommeVerte/rexpro-php

As extra information. Rexster can load graphs from various other graph dbs such as Neo4j and OrientDb among others.